# how to stop timer at 20 minutes

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timer

I am making a timer that starts when the user hits "space" and stops on "p", showing the ending time. I can I stop it at a maximum time of 20 minutes?  Is there something like

```
if time_passed==20:
    break
```

My code:

```
from turtle import*
from datetime import datetime

...

def start():
    undo()
    global break1, timerint, startime
    break1 = 0
    startime = datetime.now()
    while True:
        timerint = datetime.now()-startime
        write(timerint,font=("Arial",50))
        undo()
        if break1 == 1:
            break


def stop():
    global break1, timerint, startime
    timerint=datetime.now()-startime
    write(timerint,font=("Arial",50))
    break1 = 1


# Turtle placement code removed
onkeypress(start,"space")
onkeypress(stop,"p")
listen()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.  There are various Python timers available on line; how did you not find them in your pre-posting research?

Comment: what fun is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can always check elapsed time with the time.time() method.

```
import time
start = time.time()

while ...
    ....
    now = time.time()
    if now - start > 20 * 60:
        break
```

That's the low-tech version.  If you want more sophisticated things, such as a separate timer process, try a full browser search for "Python timer process".

---

Also, you might consider using Boolean values:

```
global timer_running, timerint, startime
timer_running = True
startime = datetime.now()
while timer_running:
    timerint = datetime.now()-startime
    write(timerint,font=("Arial",50))
    undo()

def stop():
    global timer_running, timerint, startime
    timerint = datetime.now()-startime
    write(timerint, font=("Arial", 50))
    timer_running = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend getting rid of the `while` loop and instead build upon turtle's `ontimer()` events:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from datetime import datetime

FONT = ("Arial", 50)

def start():
    global timer_running, start_time

    if timer_running:
        return

    start_time = datetime.now()
    timer_running = True

    screen.ontimer(lambda time=start_time: automatic_stop(time), 20 * 60 * 1000)
    screen.ontimer(update, 100)

def update():
    if not timer_running:
        return

    timerint = datetime.now() - start_time
    marker.undo()
    marker.write(timerint, align='center', font=FONT)

    screen.ontimer(update, 100)

def manual_stop():
    global timer_running

    if not timer_running:
        return

    timer_running = False
    timerint = datetime.now() - start_time
    marker.undo()
    marker.write(timerint, align='center', font=FONT)

def automatic_stop(time):
    global timer_running

    if timer_running and start_time == time:  # make sure *this* timer is still valid
        timer_running = False
        marker.undo()
        marker.write("Expired!", align='center', font=FONT)

screen = Screen()
marker = Turtle(visible=False)
marker.penup()
marker.write("Hit 'space' to start timer; 'p' to stop", align='center', font=FONT)

start_time = None
timer_running = False

screen.onkeypress(start, "space")
screen.onkeypress(manual_stop, "p")

screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

We pass `automatic_stop()` a copy of `start_time` so that when it wakes up in the distant future it can check if it is still a valid end event or not based on the current `start_time`.  (If you work at the Tk level instead of turtle, you might be able to cancel the timer when no longer needed.)